# Facebook api, how to test if the an action has permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing an automated posting system, so a user can post stuff through my app. The problem is that I would like to detect if the post will be possible, before I perform it.

Some users have public posts but don't allow replies, if I try to reply to their post I'll get:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#210) User not visible","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}
```

I would like to check if it is possible to perform my action before I do it. Posting a test token and afterwards deleting it's not an option.

If anyone has any hints please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FQL user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) has a column `can_post`:

> can_post | bool | Whether or not the viewer can post to the user's Wall.